# concatenate in swift: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'AnyObject'

Tags: parse-platform, concatenation, swift2

I get the error in Swift and don't understand it when I do this:

> if(currentUser["employer"] as! Bool == false) { print("employer is
>   false: "+currentUser["employer"] as! Bool) }

But I can do (Its not actually printing anything though, maybe another problem):

> if(currentUser["employer"] as! Bool == false) {
>   print(currentUser["employer"]) }

Results in error:

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and
>   'AnyObject'

Similarly:

```
                let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()!
                let isEmployer = currentUser["employer"]
                print("isEmployer: \(isEmployer)")
                print(currentUser["employer"])
```

But these two don't work:

```
                print("employer: "+currentUser["employer"])
                print("employer: \(currentUser["employer"])")
```

I also happen to be using Parse to get data, and not sure if that is the right way either.

Comment: could you specify the error?

Comment: The error was in the title, exactly as is: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'AnyObject'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message might be misleading in the first example

> ```
> if currentUser["employer"] as! Bool == false { 
>  print("employer is false: "+currentUser["employer"] as! Bool) 
> }
> ```

In this case, the error message is supposed to be

> binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'Bool'

because `currentUser["employer"] as! Bool` is a non-optional `Bool` and cannot be implicitly cast to `String`

Those examples

> ```
> print("employer: "+currentUser["employer"])
> print("employer: \(currentUser["employer"])")
> ```

don't work because

- In the first line, `currentUser["employer"]` without any typecast is an optional `AnyObject` (aka unspecified) which doesn't know a `+` operator.
- In the second line, the string literal `"employer"` within the String interpolated expression causes a syntax error (which is fixed in Xcode 7.1 beta 2).

---

Edit:

This syntax is the usual way.

```
let isEmployer = currentUser["employer"]
print("isEmployer: \(isEmployer)")
```

Or alternatively, you can write

```
print("employer is " + String(currentUser["employer"] as! Bool))
```

Comment: ok. So last example will be a feature added in the future, but the first two are casting errors and is just something that can't be done with swift?

Comment: It can be. Your code  `let isEmployer = currentUser["employer"]
                print("isEmployer: \(isEmployer)")` is the proper way. Or you can write `print("employer is " + String(currentUser["employer"] as! Bool))`

Comment: print("employer is " + String(currentUser["employer"] as! Bool)) is what I was looking for...which is too tedious! But now I clearly understand what is going on. So I should cast it myself in a variable first. With simple stuff, I've gotten away with using +. Thank you.